# Getting incorrect value when I return value from a fulfilled promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Struggling to get a value from a promise.

When I resolve the promise and console.log the result I see this:

```
46 38
```

This is the correct value I expect to see. However, when I call the method that is supposed to return this promise (receives data from a websocket), I get this:

```
user id is matched_id 1096
```

This is my code. This is the method that receives data from my websocket:

```
  async sendData(data){
    if(this.socketRef.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
        console.log('we are still waiting')
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('now opening websocket')
            this.socketRef.addEventListener('open', resolve);
        });
    }
    console.log('now sending', data)
    this.socketRef.send(data)
    const result =  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.socketRef.onmessage = e => {
            resolve(e.data)
        }
    });
    console.log('what is result', result)
    return String(result)
```

This is where this method is triggered:

```
function receiveWebSocketData(matchedUser, roomId){
    const userID = WebSocketInstance.sendData(matchedUser+' '+roomId)
    const fulfilled = userID.then((res)=> { return res })
    const fulfilledPromise = setTimeout(()=>{
        fulfilled.then((result)=> { return result } )
     }, 5000)
    return fulfilledPromise;
};
```

When I console.log the result from the above function this is where I receive the `1096` output.

**UPDATE** I have tried a solution from the answer I have received so far:

```
  async sendData(data){
    if(this.socketRef.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
        console.log('we are still waiting')
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('now opening websocket')
            this.socketRef.addEventListener('open', resolve);
        });
    }
    console.log('now sending', data)
    this.socketRef.send(data)
    const result =  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.socketRef.onmessage = e => {
            resolve(e.data)
        }
    });
    return String(result)
```

and

```
async function receiveWebSocketData(matchedUser, roomId){
    return WebSocketInstance.sendData(matchedUser+' '+roomId);
```

I then tried this console.log(await receiveWebSocketData(matchedUser, roomId)

and get the error:

```
Unexpected reserved word 'await'.
```

when I try this:

```
console.log('what am I getting receiveWeb', receiveWebSocketData(matchedUser, roomId).then((res) => console.log(res)))
```

I get this:

```
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

Comment: You're returning the result of `setTimeout` which is the id used for `clearTimeout`.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I needed the setTimeout to return the value from a fulfilled promise. I can't seem to get the value out of the promise without the setTimeout

Comment: You have to `await` in this function if you need values here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how promises work. Just return the promise.

```js
function receiveWebSocketData(matchedUser, roomId){
    return WebSocketInstance.sendData(matchedUser+' '+roomId);
};
```

To access the returned value use `await` or `.then()`

```js
console.log(await receiveWebSocketData(matchedUser, roomId));
```

or

```js
receiveWebSocketData(matchedUser, roomId).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: All of these solutions return this:

[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

When I console.log fulfilled from the function I have this is what I have at that point:

[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "46 24"

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-5aanau?file=index.ts. What you're seeing is probably an issue in your `sendData` function.

Comment: Added an update with my attempt at this solution and what I am receiving

Comment: You're misunderstanding, it's impossible for `receiveWebSocketData` to return the resolved value. Anywhere that wants to use the result needs to use one of the two methods. It looks like you're trying to do `console.log(receiveWebSocketData(...))` without using `await` or `.then()`. Also, don't add a 3 second delay to your promise, I just did that to simulate an api call. Read my answer again carefully, the changes you showed do not reflect what I wrote.

Comment: When I remove the 3 second delay and add await to my console log I get the error Unexpected reserved word 'await'.  If  I use the then() method within the console log I get this:

[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

Comment: I updated my question with what I have tried

Comment: `await` may only be used inside an `async` function. Your second attempt at logging is not what I wrote.